Question about calculating "translation" properties of theta functions
I was following this paper, but I'm stuck in trying to understand a calculation in the proof of Lemma 1.1; I was wondering if anyone could help me understand where my error is?
The proof of Lemma 1.1 uses the following transformation properties of the Jacobi theta functions:
$$
\begin{matrix}
    \theta(v+1,\tau) =  - \theta(v,\tau)  &,&   \theta(v+\tau,\tau) =  - q^{-1/2} e^{-2\pi i v} \theta(v,\tau) \\
    \theta_1(v+1,\tau) =  - \theta_1(v,\tau)  &,&   \theta_1 (v+\tau,\tau) =  +q^{-1/2} e^{-2\pi i v} \theta_1(v,\tau) \\
    \theta_2 (v+1,\tau) =  +\theta_2(v,\tau)  &,&   \theta_2(v+\tau,\tau) =  - q^{-1/2} e^{-2\pi i v} \theta_2(v,\tau) \\
    \theta_3 (v+1,\tau) =  +\theta_3(v,\tau)  &,&   \theta_3(v+\tau,\tau) =  +q^{-1/2} e^{-2\pi i v} \theta_3(v,\tau)  \;.
\end{matrix} 
$$
(Here $v$ is a complex variable, $\tau$ is a variable in the open complex upper half-plane, and $q := e^{2\pi i \tau}$.)
From this the paper author obtains the formula
$$
\theta_\nu (m(t+a\tau + b), \tau) = e^{-\pi i m^2 (a^2 \tau + 2at) }
\theta_\nu (mt,\tau)
$$
where $m$ is some integer, and $a,b$ are integers divisible by 2. In particular the above formula has no factors of $q$ showing up in the RHS. (Here $\theta_\nu$ stands for any one of $\theta,\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$.)
However, when I tried working it out myself, I got the formula
$$
\theta_\nu(v+k\tau,\tau)
= q^{-k/2} e^{-2\pi i \sum_{s=0}^{k-1}(v+s\tau)} \theta_\nu(v,\tau)
= q^{-k/2} e^{-2\pi i (kv + k(k-1)\tau/2)} \theta_\nu(v,\tau)
$$
when $k$ is a nonnegative integer divisible by 2. In particular there is a $q^{-k/2}$ factor in my formula, unlike in the paper's formula.
Could anyone help me understand what is my mistake which is causing my formula to differ from the paper's formula? (Particularly in the sense of the $q$ factors, which are there in my formula but not in the paper's formula.)
I've worked out the calculation multiple times but I keep getting the same results, and I'm not sure where my discrepancy or mistake is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
--
Update:
As the comments and answers helped explain, we have
$$
q^{-k/2} e^{-2\pi i (kv + k(k-1)\tau/2)} \theta_\nu(v,\tau)
= e^{-2\pi i (kv + k^2\tau/2)} \theta_\nu(v,\tau)
$$
since $q= e^{2\pi i \tau} $. Thank you for your help!
Also, there was an overall minus sign missing inside the exponential I wrote; I've now added the minus sign in. Thank you for helping to catch this error!

It might be better to focus on a simpler case like $(m,a,b)=(1,2,0)$. (When I test both the paper and your formula in that case, what I get from translation is $\theta_\nu(v+2\tau,\tau)=q^{-1}e^{-4\pi i v}\theta_\nu(v,\tau)$ which doesn't seem to match either your result or the paper's.)

Note that $q = \exp(2 \pi \mathrm i \tau)$. It looks like $q$ has been expanded like this in the formulas.

@Semiclassical it looks like OP has dropped a minus sign but thats it. When you apply the translation by $\tau$ step multiple times you cannot “skip” steps without getting a series in the exponent.

@LeeFisher I see what you mean.

You basically have it, just be mindful of the signs in the exponents. We have $q= \exp(2\pi i\tau)$ so you should wind up with:
\begin{align*} \theta_v(v+k\tau,\tau) &=\exp(-\pi i k\tau)\exp(-\pi i k(k-1)\tau - 2\pi i k v)\\
&= \exp(-\pi i k^2\tau -2\pi i k v)\\
&=  \exp(-\pi i m^2a^2\tau -2\pi i (ma)(mt))
\end{align*}
Which agrees with the paper.

I see; thank you for your explanation! I see my exponential term matches the exponential in the paper. Also thank you for helping catch my sign error!
